# Get the value using the hexadecimal address in c

Tags: c, hex

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getTheValue();

int main() {
    char *address;
    char num[2] = "ab";

    address = (char *)num;
    printf("Address of num: %p\n", address);

    getTheValue();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void getTheValue() {
    unsigned char address[11];
    printf("Enter the address: ");
    scanf("%s", &address);
    printf("\naddress = %s", address);
    printf("\n");
    unsigned char *ptr
    ptr = (char *)(address);
    printf("The value at address = %c", *ptr);
}
```

=====OUTPUT=====

```
Address of num: 0xffffcba6
Enter the address: 0xffffcba6

address = 0xffffcba6
The value at address 0xffffcba6 = 0
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.719 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Why am I getting the value **0**. I want the value of **num**.

Please give me some suggestions or send some links where I can know more about this.

Comment: What's up with that last paragraph of your question?

Comment: It was a mistake

Comment: It's not the value **0**. It's the character **0** since that's the first character of the string **"0xffffcba6"**.

Comment: change that to `char num[3]="ab";` to make room for the `NUL` string terminator. I would have expected a warning from that, but did not get one in either gcc or clang.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &address);` Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: OT: when writing the prototype for a function that takes no parameters.  insert `void` inside the parens of the prototype  I.E.  `void getTheValue( void );`

Answer (score 3):

Your program does not convert the string read into a pointer value. You are merely printing the first character typed by the user.

You can read pointer values from a stream with `scanf("%p", &p);`:

> **7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function**
>
> ...
>
> `p` Matches an implementation-defined set of sequences, which should be the same as the set of sequences that may be produced by the %p conversion of the `fprintf` function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a pointer to void. The input item is converted to a pointer value in an implementation-defined manner. If the input item is a value converted earlier during the same program execution, the pointer that results shall compare equal to that value; otherwise the behavior of the `%p` conversion is undefined.

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getTheValue(void);

int main() {
    void *address;
    char num[] = "ab";

    address = num;
    printf("Address of num: %p\n", address);

    getTheValue();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void getTheValue(void) {
    void *p;
    printf("Enter the address: ");
    scanf("%p", &p);
    printf("address = %p\n", p);
    unsigned char *ptr;
    ptr = p;
    printf("The value at address = `%c`, decimal %d, hex 0x%02x\n", *ptr, *ptr, *ptr);
}
```

Trace:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > ./peek
Address of num: 0x7fff5101e94c
Enter the address: 0x7fff5101e94d
address = 0x7fff5101e94d
The value at address = `b`, decimal 98, hex 0x62
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using strtol. Your "value" was just the first character of the string "0x...." from address -- instead of first converting the entire string into an integer -- and using that integer as an address.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void getTheValue();

int main() {
  char* address;
  char num[3] = "ab";

  address = (char *)num;
  printf("Address of num: %p\n", address);

  getTheValue();
  getchar();
  return 0;
}

void getTheValue() {
  char address[11];
  printf("Enter the address: ");
  scanf("%s", &address);


  char *ptr = (char *)strtol(address, 0, 16);
  printf("The value at address = %c", *ptr);
 }
```

Then ptr = "ab"  --- Note that I do not type 0x in my input however.

[image]

Comment: char *ptr = (char *)strtol(address, 0, 16); <p>Why have you used 16</p>

Comment: You should use `char *ptr = (char *)strtoll(address, 0, 16);` on broken platforms where pointers are 64 bit-wide and `long` just 32-bit.

Comment: Please do not post text output as screenshot. Simple copy&paste as plain text would be sufficient. It's not artwork.

Comment: No need to cast here: `address = (char *)num;`.